# using two instances of cartalyst sentry 2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am currently working on two laravel projects, both use Sentry2 for authentication, I am having an issue where if I log in to one app I will be kicked out of the other. I understand sentry2 is made so that you can only log in from one broswer/computer at a time, but this is two separate instances of sentry(running on the same server). I have two database and the apps are completely separate. does anyone have a work around for this? is it using the same session variable that is conflicting?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're on the same domain, it's likely that the two apps are writing over each other's session cookie in the browser.

In `app/config/session.php`, change `'cookie' => 'laravel_session'` to something unique for each app.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction! this is part of the problem. I also took a peek in the published sentry config, and there is a cookie set there as well cartalyst_sentry. I will update both to be unique.